# How use openurl & multiprocessing get URL different data in the same time?

Tags: python, csv, multiprocessing, urlopen

This loop help get some text data from web service:

```
while True:
    u = urllib2.urlopen('http://url/%d.csv' %inputd)
    f=open('/folder/%s.csv' $inputd,'a')
    csvread = csv.reader(u)
    csvwrite = csv.writer(f)
    csvwrite.writerows(csvread)
    print 'OK','%e'%inputd
    time.sleep(30)
```

now I try to get different data title in the same time use multiprocessing:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import urllib2,csv,random,logging,csv,time

inputd=(abc,def,ghi)

def dataget():
    u = urllib2.urlopen('http://url/%d.csv' %inputd)
    f=open('/folder/%s.csv' $inputd,'a')
    csvread = csv.reader(u)
    csvwrite = csv.writer(f)
    csvwrite.writerows(csvread)
    print 'OK','%e' % inputd
    time.sleep(30)

process=[]
for s in inputd:
    p = mp.Process(target=dataget) 
    ps.append(p)
    p.start()
```

I hope this can do the getting and saving of "http://url/abc.csv"; "http://url/def.csv"; "http://url/ghi.csv" at the same time, then re-do it again after `time.sleep`. But it doesn't work, or do same process in the same time, what logic error did I make?

Comment: You import csv twice by the way.

Comment: Thanks,I see import csv import error.:)

Comment: @Jeff:you mean paste original sources code?

Comment: Yes.  The code [you pasted in](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/eb7b9b61-494f-4edb-8dcc-e94df59e87e3/view-source) was not indented at all.  Others added the indentation for you (not the right move IMHO) but they could be completely wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your multiprocess implementation will do the url grabbing only once.
If you want that your dataget do the stuff again and again, you missed the `While True`.

Maybe like this it will work :

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import urllib2,csv,random,logging,csv,time

inputd=(abc,def,ghi)

def dataget(param):
    while True:
        u = urllib2.urlopen('http://url/%d.csv' %param)
        f=open('/folder/%s.csv' %param,'a')
        csvread = csv.reader(u)
        csvwrite = csv.writer(f)
        csvwrite.writerows(csvread)
        print 'OK','%e'%param
        time.sleep(30)

process=[]
for s in inputd:
    p = mp.Process(target=dataget, args=(s,)) 
    process.append(p)
    p.start()
```